# ESP chips vs AVR

Tags: avr, esp8266, esp32

I recently got an Esp32 module and I was wondering how does Esp chips differ from AVR chips in general. What I know is there is a huge difference in specs and peripheral of the two, as the chip's silicon itself, but what I cannot understand is how does programming Esp chips differ from programming AVR chips. I know that Esp has arduino core and is supported by micro python, but in case of, AVR (in a nutshell) I just have to set or clear different bits in different registers to configure peripheral and so on. Can Esp chips be programmed that way? I am just looking for general understanding of the differnece in programming Esp and AVR chips. Like the concept in general.

Comment: Arduino is a programming environment that can be used to develope software for several different micricontrollers including AVR, ATMega, EPS32...  Micropython is a programming language that is available for many different microcontrollers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All microcontrollers (AVR, PIC, ARM cortex M, ESP, 8051) work the same way: registers control peripherals and read/write peripherals, commands/programs are stored and executed moving around data between peripherals. There's are just different levels of abstraction to do that.

For all microcontrollers, you can always write in assembly code. Every microcontroller will have different instructions you can use. Next level up, microcontrollers typically have some kind of standard C library for compiling C into useful machine code. For ESP, see https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/. For AVRs, see avr-libc https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/pages.html or Atmel's toolchain https://www.microchip.com/en-us/development-tools-tools-and-software/gcc-compilers-avr-and-arm, and for ARM see CMSIS https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/embedded/cmsis.

There are even higher levels, for example Arduino which is a bunch of additional libraries built on top of avr-libc that provides the same code interface (API) for AVR, ESP, and ARM for the most part. But they aren't the only one that does that. Some vendors try to do that as well too. For example, start.atmel.com tries to make s consistent high level API for all their devices, kind of like arduino does, in a way.

The lower level you go, you will generally be more powerful and efficient at the cost of difficulty reading and understanding code, and code being extremely device specific. Higher level abstractions (arduino) are easy to read, can likely work on other chips, but can be slower and bloated.

The short answer to your question: yes you can do low level coding on an ESP chip just like an AVR chip. But there are different layers, and you get to choose where you want to work!

Answer (score 1):

> I just have to set or clear different bits in different registers to configure

This is how you program every processor at the lowest level.

But that doesn't mean things are organized the same. For example, ARM cores are in many different processors from many different manufacturers but they they all program quite differently because the peripherals used are different and the difference in design philosophy has caused the registers to be set up and organized differently. And of course, the organization and way the datasheets and manuals read are also different.